# Error in library(qdap) : there is no package called ‘qdap’

Tags: r, rjava, install.packages, qdap

I've installed qdap:

```
install.packages("qdap")
```

It takes a while to donwload everything but the console fills up with all the downloads and at the end I get a message like this:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘qdap’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpeTzuKz/downloaded_packages’
> library(qdap)
Error in library(qdap) : there is no package called ‘qdap’
>
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666638/cant-access-user-library-in-r-non-zero-exit-status-warning) SO post led me to try adding `dependencies = TRUE` but the issue remains.

Here's session info

```
sessionInfo():
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0
```

Another post I found yesterday (cannot find it again now with a Google search) suggested I remove existing qdap files within my library directory, close my session, restart and fresh install. There was no package exactly called qdap but some with qdap in the name which I removed. My issue remained, I am unable to install qdap.

I'm not sure what other information to provide? Any help appreciated.

Here are the errors generated when attempting to install qdap:

> ./configure: line 3736: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java: No
>   such file or directory no configure: error: Java interpreter
>   '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java' does not work ERROR:
>   configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
>   * removing ‘/home/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘rJava’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for
>   package ‘openNLPdata’
>   * removing ‘/home/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/openNLPdata’ Warning
>   in install.packages :   installation of package ‘openNLPdata’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for
>   package ‘xlsxjars’
>   * removing ‘/home/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/xlsxjars’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘xlsxjars’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for
>   package ‘venneuler’
>   * removing ‘/home/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/venneuler’ Warning
>   in install.packages :   installation of package ‘venneuler’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘openNLPdata’, ‘rJava’ are
>   not available for package ‘openNLP’
>   * removing ‘/home/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/openNLP’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘openNLP’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘rJava’, ‘xlsxjars’ are not
>   available for package ‘xlsx’
>   * removing ‘/home/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/xlsx’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘xlsx’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies ‘openNLP’, ‘venneuler’,
>   ‘xlsx’ are not available for package ‘qdap’
>   * removing ‘/home/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/qdap’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘qdap’ had
>   non-zero exit status

Since this looks like a rJava issue I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing) post and tried the top voted answer in the terminal:

```
apt-get install r-cran-rjava
```

Resulted in:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I'm hoping theres a way around this without being a root user? I'm not as familiar with linux. I'm able to install other p packages.

Comment: You may want to include actual errors in the installation to identify what is going wrong.

Comment: Done. Looks like a rJava issue

Comment: What happens if you try `apt-get install r-cran-rjava`? It seems that the issue for installing rjava is about the permission.

Comment: @amatsuo_net that's what I tried per the top answer in the linked to post but I got the errors "E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?". I actually had our sys admin fix it for me, maybe I should delete now?

Comment: Sorry what I meant was using `sudo`. What happens with `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava`? If you know what your sys admin did to resolve, you can post it as an answer and close. That might help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution for this issue when you have no root access.

1. Download Java (make sure to install JDK) and install it inside your $HOME

   You can do that as Oracle's Java is just a tar.gz package
2. Make sure to set JAVA_HOME

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/opt/my_jdk_installation
   ```
3. Once you have Java you have to reconfigure R

   Simply tell R where your Java is

   ```
   R CMD javareconf \
   JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME} \
   JAVA=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java \
   JAVAC=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac \
   JAVAH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javah \
   JAR=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jar \
   JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/server \
   JAVA_CPPFLAGS="-I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux"
   ```

Since now, R should use your personal installation of Java. This way, you don't depend on sys admin.