# R : Bar plot for time series of data corresponding to 12 months of 15 years

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataset which looks like this one below.

```
month   Yi      Yi+1
1   0.014310185 13.43838262
2   0.014310185 15.7792948
3   0.176113783 16.14479846
4   3.143663699 16.54060078
5   3.755478277 16.75810501
6   3.767263653 17.03156884
7   3.767263653 17.03156884
8   3.829219647 17.03156884
9   4.375269901 17.78482322
10  8.707536696 18.47995179
11  10.28741362 21.33942187
12  10.66218286 21.82637774
```

I have 15 columns of Y (Yi to Yi+14). Column Yi, for instance, corresponds to the volume of precipitation over the 12 months of the year Yi. I have to barplot the volume of precipitation of all years (with their months) side by side on the x axis. In the end, I have to get something like this:
![enter image description here][1]

I have already tried the `melt` and `group_by` functions to reshape my data frame following this commands:

```
df  <- read_excel("df.xls", col_names = FALSE, skip = 1)
colnames(df) <- c("month", "Yi", paste0("Yi+", 1:14)

df.melt <- melt(tab.df, id = c("month", "Yi", paste0("Yi+", 1:14))

bar <- group_by(df.melt, aes(x = 1:length(value), y = value, fill=factor(month))) +
geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity"))

ggplot(bar, aes(x=variable, y=mean, fill=factor(month)))
```

but it did not work. any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I edited my question according to your remarks! Thanks!

Comment: `melt` and `group_by` are not base R functions. Please include all `library` lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative could be to use `geom_col` and facet by year.

```
library(data.table) # for melt
library(ggplot2)

# Took the data example from @Istrel
set.seed(2018)
df <- data.frame(month = 1:12, matrix(abs(rnorm(12 * 15)), nrow = 12))
colnames(df) <- c("month", "Yi", paste0("Yi+", 1:14))
setDT(df) # just to be sure, convert to data.table; use setDF(df) to switch back
df_m <- data.table::melt(df, "month")

ggplot(data = df_m,
       aes(x = month, 
           y = abs(value),
           fill = as.factor(month))) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(variable),
             space = "free_x",
             scales = "free_x",
             switch = "x") +
  # Some graph adjustments:
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +  # remove space between plot area and x axis
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Climate variable") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Months") + # legend title
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing = unit(0.1, "cm")  # adjust spacing between facets
  )
```

[image]

Hope this is also helpful.

Comment: Thanks Valentin. when I run your script it give this error: 
`Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  The melt generic in data.table has been passed a tbl_df (not a data.table) but the reshape2 package is not installed to process this type. Please either install reshape2 and try again, or pass a data.table to melt instead.
> `

Comment: Hi. Use `setDT(your_tbl_df)` to switch it to a data.table and if you need the revert, use `setDF` function. I also updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, the error `data.table` is fixed. However, there is still this problem: `Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘stringr’`. when I try to install `stringr`, I find this error : 
`Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘stringi.so’ not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘stringr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/stringr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: I used this (from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201742/installation-of-packages-stringr-and-stringi-had-non-zero-exit-status)) to install `stringr` : `install.packages("stringi", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
install.packages("stringr", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))` It worked perfectly after the installation of stringr! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can melt the data frame and plot values against sequence `1:180`. Then you can assign custom labels to x-axis in order to denote years.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# Create example df with random values
df <- data.frame(month = 1:12, matrix(rnorm(12 * 15), 12))
colnames(df) <- c("month", "Yi","Yi+1", "Yi+2", "Yi+3", "Yi+4", "Yi+5","Yi+6",  "Yi+7", "Yi+8", "Yi+9", "Yi+10","Yi+11","Yi+12","Yi+13","Yi+14")

df_m <- melt(df, "month")

# Prepare labels (at each 6 month for 15 years)
x_labs <- c("Yi","Yi+1", "Yi+2", "Yi+3", "Yi+4", "Yi+5","Yi+6", "Yi+7",
            "Yi+8", "Yi+9", "Yi+10","Yi+11","Yi+12","Yi+13","Yi+14")

ggplot(df_m, aes(x = 1:length(value), y = value, fill=factor(month))) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    # add custom labels at each 6-th month
    scale_x_continuous(labels = x_labs, breaks = seq(6, 15 * 12 - 6, by = 12)) +
    xlab("year???")
```

Comment: Thanks @Istrel. The problem is that I cannot install the package `reshape2` since the installation of its dependent package `stringr` cannot be carried out. I could just install `reshape` and with `reshape` when I use `melt (df,"month")` this error occurs : `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :
  names do not match previous names`

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce your error. I have tried `reshepe` package and the code works fine.

Comment: Thanks Istrel. I tried with your random values and your script worked perfectly. But with my data.frame there is this error :
`Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names `

Comment: Can you post `str(df)` output?

Comment: `Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 12 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ Yi   : num  0.0143 0.0143  ...
 $ Yi+1 : num  13.4 15.8 ..
 $ Yi+2 : num  22.7 23.2 ..
 $ Yi+3 : num  36.5 37.6 ..
 $ Yi+4 : num  45.8 45.9 ..
 $ Yi+5 : num  49.2 49.3  ..
 $ Yi+6 : num  51.5 51.5  ..
 $ Yi+7 : num  57.5 57.6  ..
 $ Yi+8 : num  74.6 75.6  ..
 $ Yi+9 : num  77.2 77.5  ..
 $ Yi+10: num  87.1 87.4  ..
 $ Yi+11: num  89.4 89.7  ...
 $ Yi+12: num  91.8 91.8  ..
 $ Yi+13: num  96.1 96.7  ..
 $ Yi+14: num  99.3 99.3  ..
 $ month: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7  ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>`

Comment: All seems correct. Still cannot reproduce the error. Maybe just rerun an R process and try from scratch.